# sample weights in pyspark decision trees

Tags: pyspark, decision-tree

Do you know if there is some way to put sample weights on `DecisionTreeClassifier` algorithm in pySpark (2.0+)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's no hyperparameter currently in the pyspark DecisionTree or DecisionTreeClassifier class to specify weights to classes (usually required in an biased dataset or where importance of true prediction of one class is more important)

In near update it might be added and you can track the progress in the jira here

There has been a git branch which has already implemented this, though not available officially but you can use this pull request for now:
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16722

You have not specified the current scenario and why you want to use weights, but suggested work around now are

**1. Undersampling the dataset** 
If your data set has a very high Bias, you can perform a random undersample of the dataset which has a very high frequency

**2. Force Fitting the weights**
Not a nice approach, but works. You can repeat the the rows for each class as per the weight.
Eg, for binary classification if you need a weight of 1:2 for (0/1) classification, you can repeat all the rows with the label 1 twice.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18746735)

Comment: @chade_ have detailed the answers

Comment: @pratiklodha I've seen it. I removed my comment and retracted my flag.

Comment: @AbdulMalik have detailed it